# Facebook page's posts feed

Tags: facebook, rss, feed, posts, facebook-feed

Does anyone know how to fetch a facebook page's rss-feed nowadays? When I log in as a page and go to http://www.facebook.com/feeds/notifications.php?id=xx&viewer=xx&key=xx&format=rss20, I get an empty feed. Is there a corresponding "page" feed that contains the pages posts?

Thanks,
/M

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook page's posts rss feed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35035297/facebook-pages-posts-rss-feed)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The IDs in the URL below are the IDs you need to find to create your rss feed.

http://www.new.facebook.com/feeds/notifications.php?id=**YOUR_FACEBOOK_ID**&viewer=**YOUR_FACEBOOK_ID**&key=**YOUR_INTERNAL_KEY**&format=rss20

There are 3 numbers in this URL. The number that follows “id” is your Facebook ID number. This number appears twice. The last number is your Facebook Internal Key. Copy these numbers and set them aside.

Step #03: Go to your Facebook Friends Page:
http://www.facebook.com/friends/?ref=tn

Step #04: Click on the “Friends Status’ Feed” link on the page.

You should now see a RSS feed of your friends’ activities. The URL will look like this:

http://www.new.facebook.com/feeds/friends_status.php?id=**your_facebook_id**&key=**your_friends_key**&format=rss20

The second number is your Facebook Friends Key. Copy this number and put it aside.

Step # 05: Create the RSS URLs

Once you have your 3 Facebook numbers (facebook_id, your_internal_key and your_friend_key), you’re ready to make your custom RSS feeds. All you have to do to is copy and paste them into the link structures below.

---

- Status Feed

http://www.new.facebook.com/feeds/status.php?id=**your_facebook_id**&viewer=**your_facebook_id**&key=**your_internal_key**&format=rss20

- Notifications Feed

http://www.new.facebook.com/feeds/notifications.php?id=**your_facebook_id**&viewer=**your_facebook_id**&key=**your_internal_key**&format=rss20

- Friends Status Feed

http://www.new.facebook.com/feeds/friends_status.php?id=**your_facebook_id**&key=**your_friends_key**&format=rss20

- Friends Links Feed

http://www.new.facebook.com/feeds/share_friends_posts.php?id=**your_facebook_id**&key=**your_friend_key**&format=rss20

- Friends List Feed

http://www.new.facebook.com/feeds/friends_status.php?id=**your_facebook_id**&key=**your_friend_key**&format=rss20

- RSS 2.0

http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=**PAGE ID**

- Alternative option

[Facebook RSS](http://fbrss.com/)

Comment: Thanks, but this URL seems to be what I what I was looking for: http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=xx&format=rss20. This can be used without any auth or keys, for example in jGFeed, I guess?

Comment: I edited the post. Try the last link I posted. Go to the your Facebook Page and get the ID of that page. The ID is located at the end of the URL.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to tag facebook posts, so that I can filter posts from the feed depending on certain tags?

Comment: Annoyingly, the steps to find **your_friends_key** no longer work and mine _expired_ recently. This happened about 3-4 years ago as well, I remember digging around trying to find the new friends key back then.

Answer (score 3):

Just a note, Facebook deprecated their Page RSS feeds on the 23rd of June 2015. fbrss.com still seems to work though.

For more info, see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3_90_day_deprecations

Comment: Quick note, I have been using fbrss.com since this happened and it works well, actually less of a pain to use than the original RSS feeds. Only down side is the re-authentication, as I keep forgetting :P

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Find your Facebook ID of the page: http://findmyfacebookid.com/

Step 2: Add the ID at the end of following url string

http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id="ADD HERE ID NUMBER ONLY"

e.g. facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=100001463662167