# Is there a way to get RSS feed of facebook page?

Tags: facebook, rss

Problem: I want to display the posts from my facebook page on a PHP page.[When there is a new post on the facebook page, my PHP page should also render the same]

Way1: If there is a way to get a RSS feed of the facebook page i can parse the RSS and display it in the PHP page. **But i am not able to find a way to get the RSS feed.**

Way2:Another way is to use FB Api. But what API can i use? Never worked with facebook API's so any help would be great.

Any other way to solve the problem is welcome!

Comment: Related: [Facebook page's posts feed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10190529/456814).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook has a universal page RSS feed:

`https://facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=PAGE_ID_HERE&format=rss20`

You may simply retrieve and sanitize the data accordingly.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't seem to work for me (perhaps it's a privacy settings thing?)  If you want everything on your wall (not just your own status posts, go to your notifications page and select RSS at the top where you have the options of getting either Text Message alerts or an RSS feed of what's on your wall.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: 
Find your Facebook ID of the page:
http://findmyfacebookid.com/

Step 2:
Add the ID at the end of following url string

http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id="ADD HERE ID NUMBER ONLY"

e.g.
facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=100001463662167